# Excel vlookup() the right function to use?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm not sure if `VLOOKUP()` is the function I am looking for, but here is the spreadsheet that I am working on: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ap96QeCBYRNtdDlpX0lONDg1YThLN1M5YkNlT1FBeFE

What I am basically trying to do is use the values in cells **E18:P18** to determine whether or not my values in cells **E4:P7** should be replaced or not. If there is a value other than **0** in that range, then it should take the values from the appropriate column in the range of **E13:P16** and replace them into the appropriate item.

So, for this example, we are replacing item values 1 (weapon #1), 3 (off-hand), 4 (helm), and 5 (shoulders). The expected results can be seen on the spreadsheet and these are the values that I would like to show up in the Equipped Item. Is there a way to easily achieve this through an excel formula? If so, what is the best way to use it?

Comment: This is not a programming question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After our discussion, here's what I think you should do.

In the Expected Results table, try this formula out in cell E31:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$17:$P$20,ROWS($1:1),MATCH(VLOOKUP(E$30,$A$4:$B$17,2,FALSE),$E$22:$P$22,0)),E4)
```

Once you paste it in, you can copy down and the formula will adjust accordingly.

Here is a picture of the expected results based on your info:
[image]

Please let me know if this is the desired result :)

Comment: I just saw your edit in my spreadsheet. I neglected to mention that the range E18:P18 does not necessarily correspond to the column headers for the Equipped Items. Basically the functionality that I am looking for is that if I would like to shop for new Shoulders, I can compare several different sets of Shoulders in cells E13:P16. The spreadsheet should then monitor cells E18:P18 for the appropriate Shoulder item value (5) and replace the Shoulders' stats. Can this still be achieve through an Excel function or would you recommend a VBA solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow what you mean.  In your spreadsheet you say that you don't include the column headings because you want to compare multiples of something (say, shoulders), but how do you know how many "shoulders" you're comparing?  Also, I don't see how the Equipped vs Replacement gets you the Expected results.  Can you please explain further on one particular example (including multiple choices of one item)?

Comment: Sure, so for the equipped versus the replacement, the spreadsheet is monitoring cells E18:P18 to look for a value other than zero. If it is a value other than zero, it should compare the number to the item values to replace the appropriate item. So for the example I have given, weapon #1, off-hand, helm, and shoulders would be replaced because there are values 1, 3, 4, and 5 respectively in cells E18:P18.

Comment: The spreadsheet is going to be used for shopping for items. Generally when shopping, you are comparing multiple stats for the same item. So say the user is looking to compare 12 different shoulders. They would put the stats for all five of the shoulders in cells E17:P20. For comparison purposes, the user would then activate the shoulders they are comparing (they are comparing to their currently equipped shoulders) by placing a value of 5 in the appropriate cell (in the range E22:P22. It will be up to the user to ensure that only one pair of shoulders is activated at one time.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. Two more questions: what does A3:B17 have to do with anything?  And is the example of E17:P20 all different shoulders to choose from?

Comment: A3:B17 is simply a reference table for users to understand what item values correspond to which item. And yes, the examples in E17:P20 can be stats for different shoulders.

Comment: Ooooh.  So for E22:P22, if it says 3 that means it's an Off-Hand stat, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15792/discussion-between-raphnguyen-and-joseph4tw)